# How to submit the form after log back in when session expired?

Tags: asp.net

My ASP.NET project now doing this:

1. Warning users session will be expired in 5 mins.
2. After session expired, when user click "submit", it redirect to the log in page.

How can I "submit" the page after log in, continue execute what it suppose to do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to implement this method mentioned here http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=453 on the page where user is working